# Specific error page when throwing error

Tags: php, symfony

I would like return a specific response when i throw an specific error. Exemple:

For a throwing like:

```
throw new NotAllowedForUnconfirmedEmail();
```

automattically send an json response with personalised data without catch throw in each controllers. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

After catching exception u can build a response. Remember that works only before sending any output.

```
try {

    throw new NotAllowedForUnconfirmedEmail();

} catch (NotAllowedForUnconfirmedEmail $e) {

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $json = json_encode($personalizedData);
    echo $json;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I would like tu "automatize" it: Specifie how symfony generate the response in case of this throw. Not write the response in each action myself. Sorry, i will update my question :)

Comment: Im not so familiar with symfony but i think u have an errorplugin or an exceptionListener, where all exceptions will be catch. there u can evauluate ur exception to "automize" a json response.